# Assign CRTP static members at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, crtp

I have a set of classes which I am extending using the CRTP to do a mixin-style so that each type can have separate static member variables. All of the classes inherit from GdsDataObject. There are 36 separate classes that do this, and they do not have uniform class mixins. This is an example of one of the classes, names GdsAircraft.

```
template <typename T>
class GdsMixinLOD
{
protected:
  static unsigned int min_lod;
  static unsigned int max_lod;
}

template <typename T> unsigned int GdsMixinLOD<T>::min_lod = 10;
template <typename T> unsigned int GdsMixinLOD<T>::max_lod = 1000;

class GdsAircraft :
  public GdsDataObject,
  public GdsMixinLOD<GdsAircraft>,
  public GdsMixinShared<GdsAircraft>  // Mixin shared by all classes
{
  ...
}
```

At runtime I load configuration options from a file and set the static member variables using those values. Right now I use a loop to detect the data type the option is meant for and then call one or more template functions to assign the values. I have to manually call additional functions for classes that have additional mixins.

```
template<typename GdsType_T>
void setGdsStaticConfigLODValues(const OptionTokens &options)
{
  for(auto &data_type_option : options) {
    if(data_type_option.first == "MIN_LOD") {
      GdsType_T::min_lod = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(options.second);
    } else if(data_type_option.first == "MIN_LOD") {
      GdsType_T::min_lod = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(options.second);
    }
  }
}

template<typename GdsType_T>
void setGdsStaticConfigSharedValues(const OptionTokens &options)
{
  for(auto &data_type_option : options) {
    // Loop just like in setGdsStaticConfigLODValues function
  }
}
```

I want to do all this with a single template function instead of having to write a separate function for every mixin and manually keep track of which classes have what mixins. The single function should somehow be able to set static variables for classes that actually have those variables.

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: It's in there... I'll move it to the end to make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I read that before it was moved. A lofty goal, but wasn't/isn't a question. I think I understand though. You're trying to have a dynamic-traits loader initialize static members using a shared algorithm fed by a derived configuration template. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for. I thought maybe there was some sort of template-based trick in C++ that I didn't know about. Alternate ways of achieving the same thing are fine too.

Comment: The fact that you'e already specifying a divergent configuration based on the derivation type makes holding the data in the template-base itself little more than a convenience. Ultimately you're going to have to specify the values of your statics *somehow*, and short of a static mapping system I'm somewhat at a loss to how to do it with even a non-simple semi-voodoo template. I'd have to ponder for awhile to come up with something different than what you already have, but in the end what you have now is at least *understandable*, and something more elaborate will likely fog that lens.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I'd have preferred to do it a different way altogether, but it's not possible to change it at this point.